Ubuntu OpenSSH sftp server
I installed OpenSSH. Changed the sshd_config. Created a user.

I created a user, but I get a error when connecting with WinSCP. Why? (Networkerror: Software caused a disconnect)

update your question to include config as text (not an image). https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask
